# BeautifulSoup - How to get all text between two different tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get all text between two tags:

```
<div class="lead">I DONT WANT this</div>

#many different tags - p, table, h2 including text that I want

<div class="image">...</div>
```

I started this way:

```
url = "http://......."
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
source = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

start = soup.find('div', {'class': 'lead'})
end = soup.find('div', {'class': 'image'})
```

And I have no idea what to do next

Comment: u can try the next_sibling attribute,and use a loop to find the node until the end one

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of this. A decent parser can do `.lead ~ :has(~ .image)` but I haven't seen anything in Python that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it let's the parser start at class lead and exits the programm when hitting class image and prints all available tags, this can be changed to printing entire code:

```
html = u""
for tag in soup.find("div", { "class" : "lead" }).next_siblings:
    if soup.find("div", { "class" : "image" }) == tag:
        break
    else:
        html += unicode(tag)
print html
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't stop at <div class="image">

Answer (score 0):

try using the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
    <html><div class="lead">lead</div>data<div class="end"></div></html>"
    """, "lxml")

node = soup.find('div', {'class': 'lead'})
s = []
while True:
    if node is None:
        break
    node = node.next_sibling
    if hasattr(node, "attrs") and ("end" in node.attrs['class'] ):
        break   
    else:
        if node is not None:
            s.append(node)
print s
```

using next_sibling to get the brother node.

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'class' - if hasattr(node, "attrs") and ('end' in node.attrs['class'] )

Comment: Sure:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "........py", line 406, in <module>
    if hasattr(node, "attrs") and ('image' in node.attrs['class']):
KeyError: 'class'

Comment: i see,this refers to the node has no attribute 'class', i think u can solve it by  first judge whether the attrs dict has the class