# how to extract xml text between two tags with a specified attribute value using beautiful soup

Tags: xml, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup

Good day,

I'm learning python while also learning about xml: as such, please forgive my ignorance.

I have an xml document with text for which I am trying to extract the into a single line: ultimately i'm wanting to create a csv file with information extracted from the attributes (as columns) with the text and for each "chunk" a new row would be created in a data frame.

here is an example of the xml file:

```
<div type="majorSection">
<p>
<tagname ID="xxx.1.1" sID="xxx.1.1.seID.00002" n="1" />
<w lemma="ref:H75">text I want</w>
<w lemma="ref:H40"> more text I want</w>
<w lemma="ref:H83">and</w>   
punctuation is on this line without any associated tag.
<tagname eID="xxx.1.1.seID.00002" />
<tagname ID="xxx.1.2" sID="xxx.1.2.seID.00003" n="2" />
<w lemma="ref:H75">second line of text I want</w>
and punctuation is on this line without any associated tag ":"    
<w lemma="ref:H8 ref:H14">and again wanted text</w>
with final punctuation line here.
<tagname eID="xxx.1.2.seID.00003" />
```

I think I understand how to do this if I was interested in the full tag "p" (paragraph) but I'm specifically interested in the text between the tags "tagname" where the sID starts the chunk and the eID ends the chunk of the same desire string.

so for the above example I would want the end result to look like

-- for first row text --  "text I want more text I want and punctuation is on this line without any associated tag." (this is from sID = xxx.1.1.seID.00002)

-- for second row text -- "second line of text I want and punctuation is on this line without any associated tag: and again wanted text with final punctuation line here." (this is from sID = xxx.1.2.seID.00003)

Ultimately I would like to have a column in the end data frame to ID the source and in this case the first row entry would have "xxx", "1", "1" and the second row entry would have "xxx", "1", "2".

so the end would have four columns: book, chapterNum, textNum, textChar

this is what I have so far but not sure how to get the textChar stored onto a single line without the line breaks nor am I sure how to get the other information from the sID attribute values that I want and put it all into a dataframe.

```
for i in soup.find_all('div'):
if i.get('type')=='majorSection':
    for j in i.find_all('p'):
        for tag in j.find_all('w'):
            textChar = tag.text + tag.next_sibling
            print(textChar)
```

I have looked at this solution to no avail:  [How to get all text between just two specified tags using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808776/how-to-get-all-text-between-just-two-specified-tags-using-beautifulsoup)

Thank you for your patience with me. I have a lot to learn on text mining with python and am excited to do it but after these last two days I'm at a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

After much toil here's the solution I managed to put together.  I'm sure are much more efficient ways of doing this but I'm unaware of any of them: sadly.

```
 verseID = tagvalue
            node = soup.find('tagname', {'sID': tagvalue})
            s = []
            while True:
                if node is None:
                    break
                node = node.next_sibling
                if hasattr(node, "eID") and node.get('eID') == tagvalue:
                    break
                else:
                    if node is not None and hasattr(node, 'text'):
                        if hasattr(node, 'type') and node.get('type') == 'value i do not want':
                            break
                        else:
                            s.append(node.text)
                    else:
                        if hasattr(node, 'type') and node.get('type') == 'value i do not want':
                            break
                        else:
                            s.append(node)
            textChar = ''.join(s)
            textChar = textChar.replace("\n", " ")
```

For completeness in case somebody else views this: I managed to put this together from the answers in this thread: [BeautifulSoup - How to get all text between two different tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346928/beautifulsoup-how-to-get-all-text-between-two-different-tags)

Thank you.